# Sum for 90days starting when user enters 1

Tags: vb.net, excel

Stackers,

So i have this spreadsheet, looks something like this....

[image]

I would like to create some sort of macro, that would look at the value 1 or 2  and start summing in "# in 90 Days" column for 90 days from where the value 1 or 2 is entered.

Is it possible what i am trying to do, or i keep doing this which i already have been doing.  --> `=sum(xxxx:xxxx)`

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Generally speaking, you're not going to be able to write a macro that is faster than a built in Excel function.  Are there values before the 1 or 2 that you want excluded (it's hard to tell from your screenshot since the data starts at the 1 {the number above the 03/25/2014 date})?

Comment: @sous2817 no the first value either will be 1 or 2, once the macro sees that it'll then sum from that to 89 days (or cells?). Hope it make sense.

Comment: oh, I see.  so you want to sum from the first 1 or 2 and then 90 days (or cells) after...correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here's my stab at it...and it's probably overkill, but it was kind of fun to figure out, so I'd thought I'd share.  I made it as a UDF (user defined function) so you should put it in a separate module (it won't work if you put it in the code behind of one of the sheets).

You use it like:

```
=Sum90Days(E2:DA2)
```

where the range parameter encompasses the entire grid.  So in my example, the range of possibilities is E2 to DA2.   The first data point may be in cell J2, so the function will sum from J2 to 90 cells later.

At any rate, it's pretty straight forward and you should be able to modify to suit.  Just put the formula in the first "# In 90 Days" cell and copy down.

```
Function Sum90Days(possibleRange As Range)

    Dim firstValue As Variant

    firstValue = possibleRange.Find("*", After:=possibleRange.Columns(possibleRange.Columns.Count), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column

    Sum90Days = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(possibleRange.Row, firstValue), Cells(possibleRange.Row, firstValue + 90)))

End Function
```

Let me know if it gets you close and or if you're having any problems...

***EDIT***

So it occurred to me that you may have data AFTER your table, which you probably don't want to include in the summing.  This finds the starting point, then checks if the end point is outside of the table.  If it is, then it only includes up to the end of the table, otherwise it goes from the starting value to starting value + 90:

```
Function Sum90Days(possibleRange As Range)

    Dim firstValue As Variant
    Dim lastValue As Variant

    firstValue = possibleRange.Find("*", After:=possibleRange.Columns(possibleRange.Columns.Count), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
    lastValue = Application.Min(firstValue + 90, possibleRange.Columns.Count)
    Sum90Days = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(possibleRange.Row, firstValue), Cells(possibleRange.Row, firstValue + 90)))

End Function
```

**EDIT #2**

Ok, as requested below is a macro that does the same thing.  You use it generally the same way, you have to put in the columns that make up the summing area.  For instance, calling the macro like this will iterate over the table range and populate just the appropriate values:

```
Sub test()
    Call Sum90DaysMacro(Range("F14:DA50000"))
End Sub
```

Even though your passing in a huge section, the macro finds the first and last used values in the table you pass it to only iterate through the used section.

**Note** the first row value is the start of the table (in this case 14).  The last row can be some absurdly big value, like 50k).  The reason I did it this way was because I had no idea where the table starts from your screenshot above.  This will give you enough flexibility and saved me a bit of time having to figure out where the table starts and where it ends.  There may be better ways, but you get what you pay for...

Second to last bit...make sure you copy the macro and the two helper functions First and Last.

Last bit...While I could add in the coloring part, I thought I'd leave something for you to try.  It's not that hard and you should be able to figure it out with a combination of googling and macro recording.  If you get stuck, please post what you tried and I'll get you going in the right direction.

Good luck!

```
Sub Sum90DaysMacro(tableRange As Range)
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

    Dim firstValue As Variant
    Dim lastValue As Variant
    Dim firstRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim firstColumn As Long
    Dim i As Long

    lastColumn = Last(2, tableRange)
    lastRow = Last(1, tableRange)

    firstColumn = First(2, tableRange)
    firstRow = First(1, tableRange)


     For i = firstRow To lastRow
    firstValue = Application.Max(firstColumn, First(2, Range(Cells(i, firstColumn), Cells(i, lastColumn))))
    lastValue = Application.Min(firstValue + 90, lastColumn)
    Cells(i, firstColumn - 1).Value = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(i, firstValue), Cells(i, firstValue + 90)))
Next i

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub

Function Last(choice As Long, rng As Range)
'Ron de Bruin, 5 May 2008
' 1 = last row
' 2 = last column
' 3 = last cell
    Dim lrw As Long
    Dim lcol As Long

    Select Case choice

    Case 1:
        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 2:
        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 3:
        On Error Resume Next
        lrw = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                       After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                       Lookat:=xlPart, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                       MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        lcol = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Parent.Cells(lrw, lcol).Address(False, False)
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            Last = rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False)
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

    End Select
End Function

Function First(choice As Long, rng As Range)
'Ron de Bruin, 5 May 2008
' 1 = last row
' 2 = last column
' 3 = last cell
    Dim lrw As Long
    Dim lcol As Long

    Select Case choice

    Case 1:
        On Error Resume Next
        First = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 2:
        On Error Resume Next
        First = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 3:
        On Error Resume Next
        lrw = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                       After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                       Lookat:=xlPart, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                       MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        lcol = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        First = rng.Parent.Cells(lrw, lcol).Address(False, False)
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            First = rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False)
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: I quickly tired it, and get this error -- `#NAME?`. Also is it possible to turn it into macro, so enduser will only have have to press `ctrl + x` when they ready to count for employee.

Comment: @SB89 did you put the code in a new module, or in one of the sheet code files?

Comment: I added the code into new module. 
EDIT: i closed the workbook and opened again and added new module and it works this time. Let me try the updated code. Thanks

Comment: @SB89 and are you still getting the error?  It works fine on my end...That error means that it's not recognizing the formula name (it should show up in intellisense, like any other formula when you hit =.  I'm off to lunch, but I'll see about converting it to a macro after I get back. Is the table range static?

Comment: well table range isn't really static, seems like they want it to keep going for however long they want to use. But for now its designed to go from `E:HP`. And i am no longer getting an error.

Comment: ok, so are we square or do you still want a macro?  Are you getting the expected results?

Comment: Yes i am getting expected results, and yes id still like a macro.

Comment: one last req if possible, when it finds that first value + 89. Is it possible to highlight those cells? just so they could standout.

Comment: @SB89 OK, at your request, a macro has been added.  Please give it a go and feel free to mark my answer as "accepted" if it meets your expectations.

Comment: Getting following error after following your details [SS1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zlxzv3tj5wgijxk/4-1-2014%201-15-20%20PM.png), [SS2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/evn5cyz2gk7pnp3/4-1-2014%201-15-32%20PM.png)

Comment: @SB89 what are the values of firstColumn and firstValue (check the Locals window).  My test sheet worked just fine.  My guess is that there aren't any values for a given row, I didn't check for that.  If firstValue is a 0 value, let me know and I'll append my code to suit.  Is there any way you can post the workbook?  That would cut down on the back-and-forth...

Comment: @SB89  I was able to reproduce the error and I've changed the code to deal with it. Please use the updated code in the post and let me know.  If there are no values to sum, it should return a 0.

Comment: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bg0dozx1jb8a3q4/Attendance_Record_90_Day_Modified.xlsm) is the file.

Comment: @sb89 the macro assumes you have at least SOME data in the table.

Comment: yep that works now. Thanks for the help. Now to figure out a way to reset after 90 back to 0. and start counting again. Like 1-90, on 91 day tread it as 1 and count to 90 (180).

Comment: @SB89 Great!  Glad you got it sorted. If you get a moment, accepting my proposed answer will let others who have a similar problem know that it worked for you (and it may be worth them trying for their situation).

Comment: Will you be able to help me with what im trying to do now? Example: start from E10 ----> when it finds first '1' or '2' start from that cell and count + 89, after that skip those cells and start to find again first '1' or '2'. I have tried looking into loops but i couldnt figure it out. 
Thanks

Comment: @sb89 yes, please post a new question as this one has solved your original problem.

Comment: posted the new question.  
Thanks